# How to rewrite and optimize an array in a for loop with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp, vectorization, stdvector

Now I hope to optimize the assignment of the inliers vector in parallel. There is no requirement for the assignment order of the inliers vector. Just put the value in C that meets the if requirements into the inliers vector, but there can be no interval between the elements of the inliers. I really can't think of a good way. Can someone help me optimize it? Thank you very much. It should be noted that the judgment result in if is irregular.

The following is the modification of the original question:

Sorry, I need to add that the operation in if is about 80% likely to occur.And this is only the abstract code logic I extracted,The actual number of code iterations is more than 10^6.

```
    std::vector<int> inliers;
    inliers.resize (10000);
    int np=0;
    gettimeofday(&start2,NULL);
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:np) schedule(static)
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        if(c[i]%2==1){
            inliers[np]=c[i];
            ++np;
        }
    }
    inliers.resize(np);
    gettimeofday(&end2,NULL);
    sectiontime2=1000*(end2.tv_sec-start2.tv_sec)+(end2.tv_usec-start2.tv_usec)/1000;
    std::cout << "time:" << sectiontime2 << std::endl;
```

The result of the above code is wrong because multiple threads compete for inliers [np]

Comment: Depending on how often the `if` is true, protecting `np` from simultaneous access may cost more than you save with threading.

Comment: For that size probably you are better off just running it sequentially

Answer (score 0):

For the `pragma` block you could use a dynamic scheduler that will append new values from the `c` array whenever a core is done with its operations. However, you should try many values until you arrive at a preferable solution, but for a problem at this size, you won't really see much improvement at all.

Comment: The biggest problem with OP's parallel code is that it gives different result than the serial one. First, this should be corrected even if the code cannot be parallelized efficiently.